# Gorgeous Silverlight 'OSX ScreenSaver esque' Animation How-To?

Tags: silverlight, animation, silverlight-3.0

Any ideas How to recreate similar animations to the gorgeous colourful swirly thing on [THIS SITE](http://ux.plainconcepts.com/)?!?!

Comment: Looks very nice, but have you seen the CPU usage?!

Comment: Yikes! 88% to 90% CPU usage on my workstation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They've either implemented a particle library themselves or are using a third party one. If you download their [XAP file](http://ux.plainconcepts.com/ClientBin/Loader.xap), unzip it, you can browse the contents of the two dlls with [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

If you're looking for a similar effect yourself you'll probably need to use a particle library similar to what they are using.